# Ajax call before page load

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, controller

i have a page that loads using a normal controller action call in my ASP.NET MVC application.  The problem is that there is some data on there that I want to load after getting details from the client side.   For this reason I want some AJAX to run on the client, then for that information to be sent back to the server and only then do I want the page to load with the data that I got back from the client to be used on the server side to give back to the client some client specific information.

Is it possible to execute some AJAX before the "main" call?

Comment: You wrote way too many text explaining your problem! If you want info from the client, this means that there already must be a rendered context from where to get the info. So you can make a call during the load but not before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you could use a regular page (view) that once loaded will call your server and then you can dynamically load another page (partialview).

You must be aware that the javascript included in your page is side-by-side with the data from your controller, wrapped by ViewEngine with view's html code. So, once your JS executes View (html & data) is already being rendered in the browser.